# how convert float to 64bit binary or 32bit float to 64bit int - php

Tags: php, floating-point, binary

I have a float variable with this value: **8546033237**

I want to convert it to a 64bit binary and use this way for convert it to binary:

```
$a = 8546033237;
$b = pack("f",$a);
```

this way give me a 32bit value not 64bit.
then when I convert back it to number give me this:

```
$a = unpack("f",$b);
var_dump($a);
```

result is : **float 8546033152**

result isnt equal with initial value.

now how convert it to a 64bit binary and vice versa correctly ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this way for converting 32bit float to 64bit binary:

```
function float2binary64($in){
        $k = '';
        while (!in_array($in,array(0,1))) {
            $k .= abs($in % 2);
            $in = floor($in / 2);
        }
        $k .= $in;

        $j = strlen($k);
        for($i=0; $i< (64-$j); $i++){
            $k .="0";
        }

        $j = 0;$l[$j] = '';$m=0;
        for($i=63; $i>= 0; $i--){
            if ($m == 32) {$j++; $l[$j] = '';$m=0;}

            $l[$j] .= $k[$i];
            $m++;
        }
        $high = bindec($l[0]);
        $low = bindec($l[1]);
        $bin = pack("N*",$high,$low);

        return $bin;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not good answers

Answer (score 0):

on the manual [function.pack](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pack.php#93085) you get your answer in #93085

Comment: I read it but I did not understand that how to use it for convert float to binary. please explain more

Comment: have your server a 64-bit enabled machine and PHP distro?

Comment: no my php version is 5.4.3 and dont support 64bit ints